# How can I resize a VGroup in actionscript automatically, when some of its children are not visible?

Tags: apache-flex

I have some HGroups inside of a VGroup. Some of the HGroups may not be visible based on the user selections. I want to re-size the height of VGroup based on its children visibility.
Any recommendation would be much appreciated
The following is my code in Flex:

```
<s:VGroup id="vgroup01" visible.stateDefault="false" includeInLayout.stateDefault="false" width="100%" autoLayout="true" >
    <s:HGroup id="hgrp01" gap="3" width="100%" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle">...</s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup id="hgrp02" gap="3" width="100%" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle">...</s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup id="hgrp03" gap="3" width="100%" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle">...</s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to set the includeInLayout property to the same value as your visible property.